# Js Object Item don't set to empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, javascript-objects

I have declared an object

```
const indicators: any = {
    CONTEXT: {},
    PRODUCTION: {},
    SATISFACTION: {},
    SPECIFIQUES: {},
};
```

Then I assign values to it

```
    indicators.PRODUCTION = { _IP1, _IP2 };
    indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4 =  {};
    indicators.PRODUCTION._IP3 = {};
```

When I inspect `indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4` it's value is always set to `undefined`.
I have tried `indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4 =  new Object();` but it's not working.

What I would is to set `indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4` value to empty object.

PS: the initialisation is working perfectly with `IP3`

Comment: for me shows empty object

Comment: Can you log immediately after setting it `indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4 =  {};console.log('immediately after setting it',indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4)`? Not sure what you mean by "inspecting it" but I assume that's a console.log too and likely immediately after asynchronously setting _IP4 so the console.log I suggest adding would show that you expected the value to be set too soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the evidence of the object having an empty object in the _IP4.
So, you may be inspecting the object when the _IP4 was not initialized.

```js
const indicators = {
  CONTEXT: {},
  PRODUCTION: {},
  SATISFACTION: {},
  SPECIFIQUES: {},
};

indicators.PRODUCTION = {
  _IP1: {},
  _IP2: {}
};
indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4 = {};
indicators.PRODUCTION._IP3 = {};

console.log(indicators)
console.log(indicators.PRODUCTION)
console.log(indicators.PRODUCTION._IP4)
```

Comment: That's working now. My problem is that there where a cache activated in my node backend that sends different values.